# Trying to run a query for a period of time

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I am trying to run a query in order to pull email sends on a particular period of time. Is that possible in marketing cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. 
You can query the "Sent" data view and use the "EventDate" to filter on the time period you want.

[Sent Data View documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5)